# How do I share a pexpect instance between a processes pool?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, pexpect

I have a working Python (2.7) script that communicates with `gdb` interactively through the pexpect module. However, it's intolerably slow, and I needed to speed it up with a multiprocessing pool. I found a way to do this, but in my implementation, each one of the multiple processes has to spawn its own pexpect instance. This seems like a massive waste of computational time, since spawning each pexpect instance takes a couple minutes, and I'll have to spawn hundreds of them.

Instead of this kind of flowchart which represents the current program,

```
Process A --- pexpect A
                       \ 
                        \
Process B --- pexpect B --- Main Script
                        /
                       /
Process C --- pexpect C
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Process A 
          \ 
           \
Process B --- global pexpect process -- Main Script
           /
          /
Process C
```

I'm aware that sharing objects between multiple processes is not new ground here on StackOverflow, but those objects discussed have by-and-large been read-only in nature. I think my issue is different in that this pexpect instance can run out of virtual memory, and will occasionally need to be restarted.

This means that the shared pexpect object needs to be *writable* in each one of the multiple processes, and every one of the multiple processes needs to be told to wait until the pexpect process has finished its restart. Further, each of the multiple processes needs to be able to update their copy of the pexpect instance with the restarted version after the restart has been completed.

Frankly, I don't know if this is possible. I'm aware that under the covers, Python uses `os.fork()` to implement multiprocessing, so I'm thinking that an arbitrary multiple-writer/multiple-reader shared-memory resource can't even be built. Nonetheless, I toyed around with trying to communicate the shared pexpect object around using `multiprocessing.Manager()', but when I tried to implement communication through the manager, I got an error that the pexpect object wasn't pickle-able.

Am I just dense in thinking this is basically impossible, or can this actually be done?